# Dual boot system--Better to have 1x 2TB with separate partitions or 2x 1TB SSD?

Tags: ssd, performance

I just purchased a new motherboard with two M.2 slots and am trying to decide whether to get two separate 1TB SSDs or one 2TB drive. I'm looking at the Samsung 980 Pro, which is currently listed at $200 for the 1TB model vs.just over $400 for the 2TB. (Pretty much the same price either way).

The obvious advantage of the one chip solution is that I'll have a spare slot available for a future upgrade but I'm wondering if having separate Linux and Windows partitions on the same drive would hurt the performance. I do a lot of data processing on fairly large datasets so anything I can do to maximize input/output speeds is a big help.

In case anyone's curious, my other components are:

- Asus ROG Strix X570-E motherboard
- AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
- G.SKILL TridentZ RGB Series 4x16GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SSDs, assuming all else is equal - same speed, size etc, then there is no speed advantage in having two separate drives.

Instead you have an element of redundancy. If one fails, you still have the other - less 'eggs in one basket' syndrome.

As both OSes are not going to ever be running simultaneously, I'd see this as the only real advantage. [you could belt & braces further by having recovery for each on the other drive], though you would presumably have both backed up externally anyway.

SSDs don't care 'where' data is on a drive - they don't map partitions to actual physical locations like an old spinny rust HD - so unless you're running them too full [over 80% consistently] then I don't see wear being a decider either way.